# Trouble connecting Mac Mail app to Exchange account on Office.com

Tags: macos, exchange

I have a new email account to add to my devices.  The account is an "Exchange" account, hosted on office.com. The admin has not enabled SMTP/IMAP and isn't willing to do so (not sure why, but it isn't something I want to push).

On my iPhone and iPad I've easily added it as an "Exchange" account, and all works fine.

On my Mac, I go through the same steps and receive this message after providing my account info, saying something needs admin approval.

I've sent this to the admin, and he isn't sure what the issue is.  (His suggestion is that I use Outlook on the Mac, which I can't use for unrelated reasons, but also don't want to use.)

I'd really like to get this working. I'm looking for ideas on either:

1. Some way to add this to my Mac's Mail app, or
2. What I can suggest to the admin to change at their end to prevent this error. Obviously it's "granting permissions to this app" but I need to provide more specific details where to look and what to click.

[image: Exchange message about needing admin approval]

Comment: Try setting it up as a new 'regular email' account. My mailserver is behind office365 but I treat it as a 'non-special' account & it works just fine. [I do everything else MS-related on the web, because I don't actually want to use the MS Office structure at all on my Mac.]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tetsujin.  That requires the admin to enable SMTP/IMAP (the "regular email" protocols).  Unfortunately they aren't enabled for this domain.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Christy!  No update from IT yet (it's a small department) but I'll keep you informed.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Mitch Cohen, looking forward to your update!

Comment: Hi @Mitch Cohen! Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Comment: Thanks @Christy.  The issue is resolved; I put details into a comment below the answer below.  Thanks again for checking in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, the error occurs in the following scenario:

> [image]

Please contact your administrator and try the solution mentioned later in the picture, such as granting access to the application on behalf of their organization.

References: [Requesting not authorized permissions error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-sign-in-unexpected-user-consent-error#requesting-not-authorized-permissions-error).

Comment: After the IT person researched the issue, he couldn't find any application he needed to add on his end.  I brought my Mac laptop into his office.  He clicked the "Have an Admin account?  Sign in with that account" link in my screenshot above.  He got a very generic message (not specifying what the exact application/permission he was asked to grant).  He granted it anyway, which resolved the issue.  He went back to his admin console and didn't see anything at all that had changed.  But it's fixed - so I'll take it as a win.